# Puppeteer sometimes clicks the wrong element

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer and I Have only two click like:

```
await page.click('span[data-href="' + XXX + '"]');
var [button] = await page.$x("//span[contains(., 'Upload Picture')]");
await button.click();
```

I'm using `headless:true`, and I can see that sometimes the automation click on the other button or dropdown.

It's a problem because the click can open a modal or sometimes open a new tab and my flow is stopped.

Comment: Could it be your selector matches more elements than you thought?

Comment: No, I'm sure. Then even the click is on a random element. Sometimes on dropdown, sometimes on the button, sometimes open a new tab with an image (like open in a new tab)

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the site, but you probably want to `waitForFunction` in such a way that the area you're working with is stable.

Comment: Hi, @JEFF do you have any updates on this issue?